# What evidence do we have for the state of ecstasy in primitive cultures?

Tags: cultural-history, anthropology

I'm studying anthropology just out of curiosity and my knowledge on this field is really limited. I am interested in the state of ecstasy and its effects in primitive psychology.

What evidence do we have of rituals that at some point got to an ecstatic state? What was the significance of this state to these cultures?

P.S. Please go easy on me, it's my first post here. Edits are welcome.

Comment: Welcome to History:SE! Please take the [tour]. As currently phrased your question is off-topic as it appears to be asking about something not really framed as about *history*, and a broad request for reference material,  and will likely be closed. However, if you are able to rephrase it with the help of [ask] it might be salvageable.

Comment: I've edited this rather heavily in an attempt to bring it on topic; if someone can answer it, they will most likely provide some of the sources you need. It may prove too broad, though (I'm no expert here). Feel free to rollback if my edit doesn't meet your needs but please note that *requests* for sources are off-topic on this site.

Comment: It doesn't answer your question exactly but you will likely find this lecture on the biological (and psychological) underpinnings of religion interesting: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4WwAQqWUkpI

Comment: Soma in the Vedas seem to point in that direction.

Comment: I think you first need to define what you mean by "an ecstatic state",  Beyond that, I would suggest that people living in "primitive" cultures are not genetically different from the rest of us.

Comment: Can you clarify the meaning of the term "ecstatic state"? Have you ever experienced a traditional African (for example, from Ghana or Senegal) drum and dance troupe?

Comment: In academic literature for Biblical studies one can find some discussion of some prophetic activity in Israel discussed as the Holy Spirit causing someone to enter into an ecstatic state, as temporarily acting out of character. An example given is when King Saul was said to prophesy involuntarily and also stripped off all his clothes in 1 Samuel 19:24. You could probably launch from there to an examination of prophetic activity in general in the Ancient Near East and look at Babylonian prophets, Hittite prophets, Egyptian, Moabite, etc. Is that along the lines of what you are wondering about?

Comment: That was not the normal mode of prophecy in Hebrew literature, so it would be a mistake to associate all Israelite prophecy with 'ecstasy', but I have indeed seen articles discussing ecstatic Hebrew prophecy.